# Sonar Project vs. Sonar Module (Part of Sonar Project)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build, sonarqube

Scenario:
We have a Jenkins maven build which do sonar:sonar on the parent pom.
I want that all modules of this build appears as single sonar projects. At the moment we have just ONE Sonar Project with submodules (each maven module is now one sonar module -> subcomponent of sonar project).

I really would like to have, that each maven module is a single sonar project. And I dont want to create for each maven module a single build. Is that possible?
If that is not possible, can i customize the project list in sonar, to show the modules instead of the projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not natively supported by SQ. You can work around this if you do your `mvn install` on the parent project and then use *maven-invoker-plugin* on each submodule executing `mvn sonar:sonar`.
This way each module shows up as separate project on SQ.